# Administer user access to Windows based Server using Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

How do I configure Active Directory such that I can define which users can access a particular server?

I know that I can configure properties of the users from Domain Controller:
Active Directory Users and Computers>Users>username>Properties>Account>Log-on-to
and specify which computers the user can access.

Can I do that for a set of users and how?

Comment: If you want to configure this for just one particular server, configure it on the server using the Local Security Policy controls.  If you want to configure it for a bunch of servers, or are determined to do it using Active Directory, you can use Group Policy to set the security policy for the server(s) in a particular OU.

Comment: Can I apply a group policy on a single user or computer?

Comment: Yes.  The easiest way to do this is to put the computer into a separate OU and apply the group policy to that OU.